# Can scala's type generics figure out match/cases?

Tags: scala, types

I have some code that is similar to the following:

```
class testClass {
    class A(val next:Option[A]){
        def printA=println("A called")

    }

    class B(val someValue:Int){
        def printB=println("B called with value "+someValue)
    }

    def printStuff[T](obj:T):Any={
        obj match{
        case a:A=>{ a.printA
                    return new A(Some(a))
                    }
        case b:B=>{ b.printB
                    return  if (b.someValue==0) new B(0) else
                        printStuff(new B(b.someValue-1))
                    }
        }
    }
```

Here, I'd like for my method printStuff to return an object with the same type as the input. However, when trying to compile this, I get the following error :

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : a.type (with underlying type testClass.this.A)
required: T
return a
```

with a similar error for `return b` . I realise that I could set the return type to Any,but in my "real" code, I am applying the function in a recursive descent manner, so it would force me to add quite a few `asInstanceOf`s, something which I'd like to avoid.

Is it possible to get Scala's type system to figure out what I'm trying to write, without having to completely rewrite the function?

EDIT: I've tried to edit my example to bring out things that might be important in my real code :

- the fact that it's recursive
- the fact that its return type depends on one of the arguments.

Comment: Why `return obj` (`return` keyword is not necessary) at the end of `printStuff()` not feasible?

Comment: in my production code, I rarely return the same object, but construct other objects. I've tried to update the example to clear this part up

Comment: The above code compiled for me when I pasted it into the REPL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply overload `printStuff` for each argument type, since this is effectively what you're doing anyway?

```
def printStuff(a : A) = {a.printA; new A(Some(a))}
def printStuff(b : B) = {b.printB; new B(b.someValue - 1)}
```

Alternatively, if there's common behaviour you want to abstract out, and so keep the single method, you can go down the typeclass route:

```
trait Cloneable[T] { def clone(t : T) : T }
object Cloneable {
  implicit object AIsCloneable extends Cloneable[A] { def clone(a : A) = new A(Some(a)) }
  implicit object BIsCloneable extends Cloneable[B] { def clone(b : B) : B = if (b.someValue == 0) new B(0) else new B(b.someValue -1) }
}

def printStuff[T : Cloneable](t : T) = implicitly[Cloneable[T]].clone(t)
```

Comment: typeclass is definitely the right approach IMO.  I'm fairly sure common interface with a return type consistent with input is what is really being asked for, the problem is trying to implement it all in one place.

Answer (score 0):

You could add asInstanceOf to the return. Would that cause a problem in your production code?

Something like:

```
def printStuff[T](obj:T):T={
    obj match{
      case a:A=>{ a.printA
        a.asInstanceOf[T]
      }
      case b:B=>{ b.printB
        b.asInstanceOf[T]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have many different cases in my production code (maybe around 20), and I'd really try to avoid going that route (it seems contrary to the scala way)

Comment: I really don't think you can do it without explicit conversion (isInstanceOf), or having all your classes share a common type (implement an Interface?), or using Any as the return type. There is no way for Scala to type check a method that returns a different type depending on the value passed and a type matching construct. Of course, I could be wrong.